# Box shadow not showing up on span containing only white space

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I'm trying to decorate text with background colors, so I'm wrapping it in spans with a background color. The spans may also have a border color, and if they have a side border, it has rounded corners.

I'm running into problems when adjacent spans have different border colors but the same background color, and the span on the right has rounded left borders. In that case, the background color doesn't look continuous (because the borders are rounded), so I'm trying to fake it by applying a box-shadow to the span on the left.

That solution works in nearly all cases. However, if the span on the left contains only white-space, it looks like its box-shadow isn't shown. This doesn't appear to be a browser bug since it is reproducible in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Here is the html I'm trying to style:

```
<div>
  hello<span class="left"> </span><span class="right"><span>world<span></span>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant css:

```
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.left {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 8px 0 #ddd;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.right {
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.right > span {
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle where you can see the cases where the box-shadow does and does not show up:

https://jsfiddle.net/fraziermork/jnnjq36b/1/

Comment: OK, I see the issue now. You're referring to the pseudo-background that bleeds past the rounded corners. The background covering the glyphs is rendered by the background-color property.

Comment: Inserting a line break between the left and right spans reveals that the box-shadow is being rendered with a gap between it and the left span's box. I'm flummoxed.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that. That's super weird.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your fiddle in Chrome and the drop shadow wasn't working for either example.  The notation of your box-shadow property seems to be the problem.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ddd;
```

This style notation should work.

Comment: -moz-box-shadow hasn't worked or -webkit-box-shadow needed for several years now. I'm really surprised specifying the prefix works for you.

Comment: That is interesting.   I'm using Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) of Chrome and -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 black; definitely seems to work.

Comment: It's not the prefix, it's the notation! For some reason `box-shadow: 8px 0 #ddd;` is not applied while  other notations work:  https://jsfiddle.net/jnnjq36b/3/

Comment: @Christoph: The box-shadow *is* applied, it just cannot be seen when the span only contains whitespace for some reason. There is nothing wrong with the notation `8px 0 #ddd` - the asker completely intends for the shadow to be rendered 8px to the right of the box to create the bleeding background effect. But you're right, the notation Chris was using is different to the one used in the question.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out when I saw your comment and played around with the fiddle, but at that point the 5 minutes for editing a comment had already passed ;-) Still, it's not obvious to me, why it actually is rendered this way. Somehow it seems to comply to the standard, since all browsers agree on this.

Comment: Yep... I'm just as baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Spans have their own background colors. To be able to show a shadow from a neighbor block or span it has to be set as:

```
span {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

or

```
span {
background-color: initial;
}
```